# NSString Hindi words compare

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, unicode-string

I am trying to compare two hindi string but it says string is not equal below is the code:

```
if([@"हड़ताल" isEqualToString:@"हड़ताल"]){
                            NSLog(@"String is equal");
                        }else{
                            NSLog(@"String is not equal");
                        }
```

How can I compare two non english strings ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using provided code. `[@"हड़ताल" isEqualToString:@"हड़ताल"]` returns `YES`.

Comment: it returns NO at my side

Answer (score 2):

The strings LOOK the same but I believe the unicode characters are slightly different so it returns NO currently as you stated...

I tested it, it returned NO

I copied and pasted the first string over the second string and it returned YES

So in conclusion.. it currently isn't the same string due to encoding.